# Set Strikethrough Attribute text for a currency formatted string in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am working with a label which shows the old price of a product with strikethrough attribute. I am trying to set the strikethrough property for the attributed string but could not get the actual result.

```
let price = 1000.0
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.currencyCode = "INR"
let priceInINR = currencyFormatter.string(from: price as NSNumber)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: priceInINR!)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
            self.oldPriceLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Is there any way to set the currency formatter and strikethrough attributes simultaneously for a string?

Comment: Please add Code

Comment: which type text you give example

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 7):

Try this and see (Swift 3 & 4 compatible):

```
@IBOutlet var oldPriceLabel: UILabel!

func strikeOnLabel() {
    let price = 1000.0
    let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    currencyFormatter.currencyCode = "INR"
    let priceInINR = currencyFormatter.string(from: price as NSNumber)

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: priceInINR!)

    // Swift 4.2 and above
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

// Swift 4.1 and below
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
    oldPriceLabel.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

**Result:**

> <s>₹1,000.00</s>

**For Swift 2:**

```
let price = 1000.0
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.currencyCode = "INR"
let priceInINR = currencyFormatter.string(from: price as NSNumber)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: priceInINR!)

// Swift 4.2 and above
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

// Swift 4.1 and below
attributedString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))


self.oldPriceLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It says, NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle is not compatible.

Comment: I test this in and obtained result, what I've shown here. I can share you project file, if you want to see. Share me you contact (email)

Comment: Actually the problem occurs only with iOS 10.x. It works fine in 9.x.

Answer (score 1):

**swift**

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your Text")
attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can mention the fontsize required for a range of text along with the strikethriough

```
let dateText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "This is a test string.")


dateText.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Poppins-Regular", size: 11)!,
                            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle: 2],
                           range: NSMakeRange(0, 8))
dateText.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Poppins-SemiBold", size: 18)!,
                            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle: 4],
                           range: NSMakeRange(10, 13))
dateText.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Poppins-SemiBold", size: 15)!,
                            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle: 1],
                           range: NSMakeRange(14, 17))


// set the attributed string to the UILabel object
deadline_lbl.attributedText = dateText
```